# making a variable equal a Arraylist value within a class (Processing)

Tags: class, arraylist, processing

Hi this is my first time making a question so hopefully i have done this right :)

In my code Im trying to make a Arraylist that is within a class that only holds floats so I made this: (some information is taken away to make it easier to read)

```
class object {

    private ArrayList yc=new ArrayList<Float>();
    private ArrayList xc=new ArrayList<Float>();
    
    object(float xer,float yer,float rer){
        xc.add(10.0);
        x=xer;
        y=yer;
        r=rer;
    }
    
    void update(){
        print(xc.get(0)) 
        x=xc.get(0);
    }
    
}
```

everything else except `x=xc.get(0)` works outside of the class this assignment works but inside the class it doesn't

hope this makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you initialised the variable `xc` you specified the type of the `ArrayList` to `Float`. However, when declaring `xc`, you did not specify the type.

When you try to assign variable `x` with `xc.get(0)`, you are basically assigning *any* Object to variable `x` that was declared as a `Float`.

To solve this issue you can declare your variable `xc` specifying the [type of the ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html#:%7E:text=Parameters-,Type,type%20for%20the%20objects%20to%20be%20placed%20in%20the%C2%A0ArrayList.,-initialCapacity): `private ArrayList<Float> xc = new ArrayList<Float>();`

Also, processing offers the helper class [`FloatList`](https://processing.org/reference/FloatList.html) as well if this suits your program.

This should solve your issue, depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: that seems to work now thank you